# hibernate mapping configuration xml file for Hashmap

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am trying to push CSV data into database using hibernate. The CSV files can have any no. of columns and so the pojo class needs to be dynamic in the sense that it cannot have getter and setter as i dont know how many columns would be there.So,I used a hashmap with keys as the column names and the values corresponding to it in one particular CSV row.As I iterate over the rows the previous values will be replaced and new values will be added.

My POJO class:

```
 public class mapojo {
 static HashMap<String,String> record=new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapojo(String[] keycolumns) {
    for(int i=0;i<keycolumns.length;i++) {
        record.put(keycolumns[i],"");
    }
    }
    public static void addvalue(String[] recordvalue) {
    int i=0;
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : record.entrySet()) {
        record.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(),recordvalue[i]);
        i++;
    }
    }
```

Now I don't know how to make a mapping configuration file for a Map.It would be really helpful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update">

Comment: will the table columns be dynamic too or will they all will go into a single row cell ?

Comment: No it won't be a single row cell.